# Preencher matriz de char com palavras aleatórias

Tags: algoritmo, matriz, array, char

Estou tentando desenvolver um algorítimo capaz de obter um vetor de strings, ordenar por tamanho de palavras de forma decrescente e colocá-las dentro de uma matriz de char encaixando se possível todas as palavras. A ideia de tudo seria como criar um grid e fazer com que as palavras de "conectem" através de letras em comum, para desenhar a ideia imaginem um caça-palavras.

Ex:

```
String[] palavras = new String[]{"vidro", "plastico", "amarelo", "madeira", "metal"};

palavras = OrdernarPorTamanho(palavras, DECRESCENTE);


char[][] grid = new char[15][15];

for(int linha = 0; linha < 15; linha++)
{
    for(int coluna = 0; coluna < 15; coluna++)
    {
       // Aqui viria as verificações para colocar todas as palavras do vetor dentro da matriz
    }
}
```

A minha saída desejada da matriz seria da seguinte forma:

Ex:

```
- P L A S T I C O - - - - - -
- - - M E T A L - - - - - - -
- - - A - - - - - - - - - - -
- - - R - - - - - - - - - - -
M A D E I R A - - - - - - - -
- - - L - - - - - - - - - - -
- - - O R D I V - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

Alguém tem alguma sugestão de como fazer esse algoritmo?

Valeu :)

Comment: Qual linguagem?

Comment: @diegofm qualquer uma, mas a principio seria Java

Comment: Acho que este problema requer um algoritmo genético. Espalhar as palavras se torna complicado a medida que as palavras que já estão no quadro podem estar ocupando espaços sorteados para as próximas.

Comment: @CelsoMarigoJr Alguma sugestão de algoritimo?

Answer (score 1):

Esse problema é [NP-completo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completo), você pode usar um algoritmo [Força Bruta](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busca_por_for%C3%A7a_bruta) para resolvê-lo. Ele consiste em tentar todas as possibilidades, e parar quando uma possibilidade é um válida. Vai retornar falha quando testar todas as soluções possíveis e não encontrar nenhuma.

Uma solução usando força bruta é o [Backtracking](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking), veja esse pseudocódigo:

```
solve(words,grid):
   if words is empty:
       if grid.isValudSol():
          return grid
       else:
          return None
   for each word in words:
       possibleSol <- grid.fillFirst(word)
       ret <- solve(words\{word},possibleSol)
       if (ret != None):
          return ret
   return None
```

Nesse [link](http://bryanhelmig.com/python-crossword-puzzle-generator/), tem um algoritmo pronto em `Python`.

No stackoverflow em inglês tem essa [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33207312/5327226), acho que pode ser útil, pois a linguagem utilizada é `Java`.